# Explaination for a stepwise load displacement curve

Tags: mechanical-engineering

An experimental study to compare the stability of different plate systems made of titanium to fix fractures of the lower jaw (mandible) made of resin material.

The load displacement curve I have obtained was step wise both in the elastic region and in the post yield region. Is a step wise load displacement curve normal? How can it be explained, are there similar cases, and what is the references?

[image] explained

Comment: It looks "step-wise" everywhere.  It seems like you just used excel or something similar to plot the data.  This really has to do with how the program is showing the data as far as I can tell.  The places where it "steps" are the points of data  you gave it.

Comment: Please clarify if you are talking about the small steps (as JMac commented on) or the multiple peaks that could also be considered "steps".

Comment: my guess you just have your equipment configured wrong. Eg. you have a 0-1 volt load cell signal and your DAC is set to a 20volt range.

Comment: I mean the small steps

Answer (score 3):

From your graph, you will notice the stepped segments occur in the sloping or curved portions of the graph.

In this case the steps are most likely the result of the resolution/sensitivity of the equipment you are using.

The same issue arises on computer screens when diagonal lines are drawn on the screen. The pixels in the screens make it impossible to have a true sloping or curving line. The lines will only be straight in horizontal & vertical directions when the line is perfectly aligned with the pixels.

It is also partially the result of using digital recording equipment, as analogue equipment tends to smooth out such steps.

To mitigate such stepped regions in your data, use equipment that has a higher resolution/sensitivity.

Comment: You could also plot your data using better interpolation.  Right now it isn't trying to make it look smooth.

Comment: the stepped curve also obtained originally from the testing machine not from excel only

Comment: @taib Did it actually print out a graph, or did it read out and record different values in a text form?

Comment: yes the servohydrolic general testing machine with computer control gives the diagram of the test and the curve also it provides text file

Answer (score 0):

The step behavior of the data is almost certainly an artifact of the test setup and not of the material itself.  As @agentp mentioned in a comment, it looks like there is a mismatch between the output voltage span of your sensor and the expected input voltage span of the analog-to-digital converter.  Most oscilloscopes can be adjusted to match the span of the sensor they are reading from - you should check the documentation for whatever equipment you're using.  If the voltage of the sensor is too small for the ADC to deal with, you can use an amplifier to boost the sensor signal.

I found the following figure from [this website](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt173/slyt173.pdf) that illustrates span mismatch pretty well:

[image: Span mismatch]

In figure (a), the span of the sensor and ADC match, but there is a 1-volt offset that will result in lost data.  In figure (b), the sensor is only using half of the available span from the ADC.  This will effectively reduce the bit-depth of the sampled data, which I suspect is what happened to your data.

Comment: thank you for your help,,,,during the experiment the loading was 1mm/minite when this rate increased itthe curve apeared without stepwise..also when ihave inserted the obtained result in excel  the curve was step wise but when i have changed the format axix into larger values the step wise curve become straight line